# Kernel and Image of Composition of linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

Let $f$ : $\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $g$ : $\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ linear functions such that $(g \circ  f)(x) = x \hspace{0.4cm} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

How can I prove that:

$\mathbb{R}^{n} = Kernel(f) \oplus Image(g)$ where $\oplus$ is the direct sum.

So far i wrote this:

$\mathbb{R}^{n} = Kernel(f) \oplus Kernel(f)^{\perp}$

So if I can prove that $Kernel(f)^{\perp} = Image(g)$ I'm done. But I'm not so sure how!

Thank's a lot!

Comment: You cannot prove that $\ker (f)^\perp=\operatorname{im}(g)$, because it is generally false. In fact, in order to even talk about orthogonality you need to add a (positive definite) scalar product to the otherwise only linear structure on $\Bbb R^k$.

Comment: But in this context it's suppose to be the true. I thought i can write a basis from one and show that is the same basis from the other (?)

Comment: No, it is not supposed to be true.

Comment: It is somthing wrong here. $n=\operatorname{rank}(g\circ f)\le\operatorname{rank}(f)$, thus, $f$ has full column rank and the kernel of $f$ is zero. Maybe you mean $f\circ g$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It works for $f\circ g=\mbox{id}$, since $\ker f\cap\operatorname{Im}g =0$ is easy, plus dimensions from the rank-nullity theorem are $n-m$ and $m$.